# Error running python script

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3, perf

I am following this tutorial: [How to analyze your system with perf and Python](https://opensource.com/article/18/7/fun-perf-and-python).

While running the following `perf script --gen-script python` command I am getting an error.

```
Python scripting not supported.  Install libpython and rebuild perf
For example:
  # apt-get install python-dev (ubuntu)
  # yum install python-devel (Fedora)
  etc.
```

even though I have already install python-dev latest version.

Could anyone please help me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Did you actually *"rebuild perf"*? merely having the prerequisite development libraries on your system is not sufficient